# Can't install pygame on iMac 12.6.3 Monterey

Tags: python

I have followed https://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/

I have also  tried to install it via the python terminal and the Mac terminal   I keep getting the following error message:

```
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [34 lines of output]

```
  WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
  Using Darwin configuration...
  
  /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
  /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
  /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/82/gx_9dw5926nd_8h271w_4fp00000gn/T/pip-install-r0d2u6u4/pygame_7a53717a6a7b41a5a1e4d3f23d0f3159/setup.py", line 359, in <module>
      buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
    File "/private/var/folders/82/gx_9dw5926nd_8h271w_4fp00000gn/T/pip-install-r0d2u6u4/pygame_7a53717a6a7b41a5a1e4d3f23d0f3159/buildconfig/config.py", line 225, in main
      deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/private/var/folders/82/gx_9dw5926nd_8h271w_4fp00000gn/T/pip-install-r0d2u6u4/pygame_7a53717a6a7b41a5a1e4d3f23d0f3159/buildconfig/config_darwin.py", line 143, in main
      find_freetype(),
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/private/var/folders/82/gx_9dw5926nd_8h271w_4fp00000gn/T/pip-install-r0d2u6u4/pygame_7a53717a6a7b41a5a1e4d3f23d0f3159/buildconfig/config_darwin.py", line 110, in find_freetype
      pkg_config = DependencyProg(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/private/var/folders/82/gx_9dw5926nd_8h271w_4fp00000gn/T/pip-install-r0d2u6u4/pygame_7a53717a6a7b41a5a1e4d3f23d0f3159/buildconfig/config_unix.py", line 39, in __init__
      self.ver = config[0].strip()
                 ~~~~~~^^^
  IndexError: list index out of range
  
  ---
  For help with compilation see:
      https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
  To contribute to pygame development see:
      https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
  ---
  
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I am at my witts end.   What do I need to do to get pygame to load.  Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I'm wondering - is there a specific reason why you're using a 7-year old installation instructions from a 3rd party? Do the [instructions of pygame.org](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation) not work? Please don't answer in a comment but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767573/edit) your question instead.

Comment: Hello Peregrino69.   Python has the ability to install pygame directly from it's terminal window.   My statement states that I tried that.  I also stated that I had tried two other methods to load the file.   Yes one of them was old but I am desperate to get this fixed.   I have gone to the pygame.org site and it states that I should install it via the terminal in python.   Unfortunately, this does not work.   I am new to the Mac world and do not know all of the dependencies required by various programs.

Comment: Ah, so that's the reason for following old instruction :-) Pygame.org says it doesn't work over Python v3.11, which is the current one. As you're running a newer version of MacOS, this might be an issue - what version do you see with command 'python3 --version'? If your python3 version is 3.11, you should downgrade it first. Is the output in your question the result of installing the recommended way, command `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user`? If not, it'd be a good idea to add that output to your question; "does not work" doesn't really give any hints on what's going wrong :-)

Comment: Thank you Peregrino69   I missed that important notice.    I have uninstall 3.11 and installeed 3.10.   pygame installed perfectly.    Thank you

Comment: Happy to help :-) As you're new here, I'd recommend taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to get a handle on how these work. SE communities aren't discussion boards, the common [SOLVED] isn't used. Instead you can [write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), and then [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) it - that'll make this useful for others. You'll need to wait 48 hours before you can accept [when the answer is your own](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).